# Install Vector Linux 7.0 from USB

Tags: linux, liveusb

I am using windows, I have downloaded ISO of [Vector Linux 7.0](http://vectorlinux.com/products/vectorlinux-7.0-standard-edition) (VL7.0-STD-GOLD.iso). I don't have a CD Rom, How can I create a bootable USB of this Linux to install it on my system.

Unetbootin don't support vector linux.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Booting Linux live CD from USB?](http://superuser.com/questions/331696/booting-linux-live-cd-from-usb)

Comment: @Gareth: Have you bothered reading the answer and my comments? I am asking for specific linux distribution which is not supported by those tools

Comment: Why are we down voting this legitimate question? Man, people have been so hateful here lately. Sheesh.

Answer (score 1):

try the linux USB installer from PenDriveLinux. its pritty easy to use and works with any downloaded Linux Live ISO.

You can find it here: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Comment: just trying it.

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: odd. it worked for every distribution i tried... are you on mac or PC?

Comment: ok, i found another installer that you can try called simply: Live USB Installer. you can find it at:http://live.learnfree.eu/download

Comment: I am on PC, going to try it.

Comment: I already tried it, it don't have the option of Vector Linux 7.0

Comment: I just tried the last option of pendrivelinux, it booted VL from USB successfully, but it keep giving error there that /isolinux/init.gz is not found.

Comment: Before giving the error it shows that 'loading from /isolinux/krenel/sata ......' and the gives the above error. I entered the path /isolinux/kernel/sata manually on console which was there. Something happened and it went to next screen, showing a lot of text. But it hanged after sometime, stating that I might have missed some boot loading parameters. I plugged out power cable to get out.

Comment: ok, i really cant help you, there, never having used that linux distribution, but im glad the download worked

Answer (score 1):

The working solution is : [LinuxLive USB Creator 2.8](http://www.LinuxLiveUSB.com)

Note: Universal-USB-Installer does NOT support VectorLinux