# Multiple Live CDs on a Single USB using a Mac

Tags: linux, mac, usb, usb-flash-drive, grub

Okay, so after searching high and low, trying YUMI and XBOOT with zero success (and probably causing damage to my drive for so much reading and writing), I'm turning to the StackExchange community!

Does anyone know a way to create a multiple distro live USB? Maybe using unetbootin and manually editing the menus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered at [How can I keep multiple live/bootable ISO images on a single USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/26548/multiple-livecd-isos-on-a-single-usb-drive), though not specific to the Mac.  That it's a Mac doesn't affect you much; you've probably already discovered [Boot Camp](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1461), and [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is also an option if you want to do this while booted into OSX.