# Windows/Linux Bootdisk ISO

Tags: linux, windows-10, bootable-media, bcd, isolinux

I am currently producing a bootdisk (similar to Medicat) that will boot live/installer linux and windows  PE/install. I have managed to get bootmgr to load on the ISO but it says boot/BCD is missing. Is there a way to load BCD from alternate location using isolinux/syslinux?

My entries for Windows are as follows:

```
label 11
    menu label Multi Windows 10 Install      ==>
    com32 chain.c32
    append boot ntldr=/WindowsInstall/Windows10/bootmgr

label 12
    menu label Multi ^Windows 10 PE          ==>
    com32 chain.c32
    append boot ntldr=/WindowsPE/Windows10/bootmgr
```

Each disk for windows is stored under either the WindowsPE or WindowsInstall directories. So the BCD for Windows Installation is stored as /WindowsInstall/Windows10/boot/bcd

Comment: I don't know about other Windows PE but was facing same issue when using  Bob.Omb’s Modified windows PE : Woeusb for Linux solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

[This free tool](https://www.aioboot.com/en/) claims to do EXACTLY what you are asking about.  It's a windows program but there is also information on that page on how to pull it off from Linux.

[This is old](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1442021)  but also does exactly what you are asking about.

There is also a thread  [here](https://superuser.com/questions/26548/how-can-i-keep-multiple-live-bootable-iso-images-on-a-single-usb-drive)  in SuperUser that has a nice discussion about the process.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great answers but for anyone who is interested, I managed to pull this off using [isolinux](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=ISOLINUX) and [wimboot](https://ipxe.org/wimboot) from [iPXE](https://ipxe.org/download). Then /boot/isolinux/isolinux.cfg setup was as follows:

```
label 32-bit
menu label Windows 7 and up
com32 linux.c32
append wimboot initrdfile=/path/to/bootmgr,/path/to/bcd,/path/to/boot.sdi,/path/to/boot.wim
```

This method worked for 32-bit and 64-bit Windows Install, Recovery and PE plus I didn't need to edit BCD entries for each version.